# How to avoid overlapping absolute elements with Bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I have some elements placed in absolute positions. In responsive mode, they overlap.
I wish to start the buttons always after the text (indeterminate length)

[image]

```
<aside class="row mb-4 m-0" id="poet-bio">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 mb-4">
        <img src="aaa.png" class="img-fluid rounded-circle">
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12 position-relative">

        <p class="position-absolute top-0">Lorem ipsum</p>

        <div class="position-absolute bottom-0">
            <a href="#" class="author-categories">USA</a>
            <a href="#" class="author-categories">Novecento</a>
            <a href="#" class="author-categories">Poetry</a>
        </div>

        <div class="position-absolute bottom-0 end-0">
            <a href="#" class="float-end"><img class="social-icon" src="xxx.png"></a>
            <a href="#" class="float-end"><img class="social-icon" src="yyy.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: maybe the first thing should be to avoid absolute positioning. You probably do not need it here.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I want the links always on the bottom

Comment: Bootstrap is based on flex, so you can do this without absolute positioning. flex-grow or margin-top can push the last content to the bottom. There is many *cards* example made of BS5 that you could inspire yourself from or use.